# codeigniter date and time does not convert correctly in view

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Dates that I want to display don't display properly. This is my code:

```
$row->created_when = '2016-09-27 11:06:54'

$row->approve_when = '02:43:06 09-28-2016'

<?php if(isset($records)): foreach($records as $row): ?>
  ......
    <?php echo $row->first_name;?> <?php echo $row->last_name;?> 
 .... 
<?php if($row->approve_when==""){ ?>
      <?php echo date("M d, Y H:i A", strtotime($row->created_when)); ?>   
     <?php echo $row->status;?> 

<?php   }else{ ?>

    <?php echo date("M d, Y H:i A", strtotime($row->approve_when)); ?>   
    <?php echo $row->status;?> 

<?php   } ?>
```

but what displays in the view:

created when : *Sep 27, 2016 11:06 AM*

approve when : *Jan 01, 1970 02:00 AM*

**`approve_when` doesn't convert properly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row->approve_when = '02:43:06 09-28-2016'` this is wrong date format. for strtotime function it must be:

```
$row->approve_when = '2016-28-09 02:43:06'
```

Code for converting to proper date format:

```
$date = '02:43:06 09-28-2016';
$ar = explode(' ', $date);
$ar2 = explode('-', $ar[1]);
$properDate = $ar2[2] . '-' . $ar2[0] . '-' . $ar2[1] . ' ' . $ar[0];

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($properDate));
```

Comment: how to i convert it to become like that without changing the value?

Comment: Can't just write it in right format `$row->approve_when = '2016-28-09 02:43:06' ? This data is putted manually or from db?

Comment: this value is from the db

Comment: I've updated my answer and added code for converting your wrong date to proper one. ps: you should think to fix your db

Comment: thanks. i tried fixing the db  but now the time doesn't convert properly from 24 to 12 hr format. I'm more confused now

Comment: For function `date` parameter `H` is 24 hour and `h` is 12 hour.

Comment: Or do you mean sth else?